# How do I scale down a video without cropping?

Tags: macos, video

The title mainly says it all. I've been looking for a tool to resize a video just by scaling it down. The only options I find when googling is for cropping video but I don't want to do that. I just want to scale a video down.

Comment: What video editing software are you using?

Comment: I have iMovie and QuickTime but I'm willing to use any other free software

Answer (score 5):

[HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/) is a free open-source video conversion utility, which in my opinion, is a must-have app.  It has built in presets for video conversion all of which are customizable.

[image]

At the bottom of the attached image, you can see the original video dimensions and the scaled down video dimensions of the conversion

You can create a custom preset and enter your own dimensions

[image]

Comment: Ahh ok, I'll try it. Also where do you change the size. I must be missing that setting in the picture you sent